# HTTP URL access via C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, windows, http

Pre-requisite: Don't want to use any external url access library like cURL

Objective:
To write a windows C/C++ code to access a URL and parse its response as a string

Lets say i have following url to access via C/C++ application

```
http://152.114.32.203:3333/Aws_Simulator/latest/meta-data/product-codes
```

I want to use Windows API and achieve the same. Can anyone guide? I have come across below url but getting confused about what to put where

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384099
```

By getting confused i mean, i don't know about headers etc. I just know that the above mentioned url has to be accessed & response has to be parsed in C/C++ code.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/28719-downloading-a-file-winsock-http-c/

Comment: Ivans comment is exactly what you can use. But it depends on what you want. If you are allowed to use all modern Windows APIs there are other ways. But that is the most basic way.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't there a way of specific classes which i could use? I am allowed to use Windows API. if you could guide me then it will be great. I have shared a link but that is confusing me as i don't know how to break my url specified earlier and provide the additional info the APIs are asking for so that i could access the URL and get hold of the response as string

Comment: The Windows API doesn't have classes. It's got a C API and COM interfaces. There are of course libraries which wrap those in classes, but you seem to want to duplicate those classes. BTW: If you want classes, you can't use C and must use C++. There's no such language as C/C++, which is why SO doesn't have a C/C++ tag.

Comment: Hi Mr. MSalters , Could you please point me to C APIs? I will try using them. So far i couldn't locate them.